# LSTM Input 0 of layer basic_lstm_cell_1 in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am working with lstm using tensor flow when I am running the code it is showing me the error. the code is running fine but when I am running the function `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(lstmCell, data, dtype=tf.float64)` it is showing Value ERROR

```
import tensorflow as tf

wordsList = np.load('urduwords.npy')
wordVectors = np.load('urduwordsMatrix.npy')

batchSize = 24
lstmUnits = 64
numClasses = 2
iterations = 10000

tf.reset_default_graph()


labels = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batchSize, numClasses])
input_data = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [batchSize, maxSeqLength])

print(labels)

data = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([batchSize, maxSeqLength, numDimensions]),dtype=tf.float32)
print(data)


data = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(wordVectors,input_data)
print(data)


lstmCell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(lstmUnits)
lstmCell = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(cell=lstmCell, output_keep_prob=0.1)

value, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(lstmCell, data, dtype=tf.float64)
```

How to resolve this error using tensor flow.

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer basic_lstm_cell_1 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=2, found ndim=3. Full shape received: [24, 1, 2]
```

**the shape of the input_data is**

```
(24, 30, 1, 2)
```

**and the shape of wordVector is**

```
(24053, 1, 2)
```

Comment: What is the output of your embedding lookup?

Comment: `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn` expect input tensor with 2 dimension, in this case you are passing a 3D tensor to it, so did you try to remove the dimensions of size 1 from the shape of the tensor using `tf.squeeze`.  Like this: `value, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(lstmCell, tf.squeeze(data), dtype=tf.float64)` ?

Comment: (24, 30, 200) shape is like this

Answer (score -1):

the label shape is 4 dimension because of you feed the wrong type of data to tf,

please try to use NumberPy array or List